# When is referential constraint mandatory

Tags: odata, abap, sap-gateway

I created a service using expanded entity set method. There were two entities in the entity model connected by association. I did not keep any referential constraint between them, but it worked.

Could anybody kindly explain me when is a referential constraint mandatory in SAP netweaver gateway?

Answer (score 0):

I had a discussion about this with one of my coworkers and i looked into the OData v2 specification and didnt find anything it being mandatory. Runtime wise (expanded entity in your example) it doesnt change anything from what i have seen so far. I just use it if i really have a superset of key properties in the depended entity, because this constraint gets written into the $metadata xml file. I had a discussion about with my coworker because they demanded a constraint on some association because else it wasnt able for them to mock data via a JS(or UI5?) mockserver. So i looked in the specification to see if i did something wrong but didnt find anything about it. so i think its optional, as generation via SEGW also doesnt seem to care wether its there or not. My advise would be to use it if it makes sense, else dont